# Eclipse IDE - unable to export to .jar: "not on its project build path"

Tags: java, eclipse, jar

I have been breaking my head for a couple of weeks now over an error I get when I try to export a .java file to a .jar in the latest version of Eclipse IDE ([screenshot of export settings / project tree / error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/98XIP.png))

I am coding for a trading platform, called 'MotiveWave', and I can export other Studies / .java files just fine (so my build path should be ok, right ?)

I get:

- JAR creation failed. See details for additional information.
  MW/Studies/MotiveWave Studies/src [in motivewave] is not on its project's build path
- Unable to get package fragment root: motivewave/MW/Studies/MotiveWave Studies/src/ChoppinessIndex.java
- MW/Studies/MotiveWave Studies/src [in motivewave] is not on its project's build path
  MW/Studies/MotiveWave Studies/src [in motivewave] is not on its project's build path
- Unable to get package fragment root: motivewave/MW/Studies/MotiveWave Studies/src/ChoppinessIndex.java
- MW/Studies/MotiveWave Studies/src [in motivewave] is not on its project's build path

when I try to export some of the .java files. All the others export perfectly, without a glitch

Please tell me how I can debug this further, because I am too unexperienced to grasp completely what this particular error message means (and why it only occurs on some of the exports).

Comment: Run your java class having main method for that package. It will create the run configuration for that proj/pkg. while exporting select correct run config and try to export.

Comment: I'm sorry ,@AjayKumar but I do not understand. When I right click the .java file and select "run as", Eclipse first wants me to create a 'run configuration'. Under, 'Java Application', I tried looking for a main class, but the search shows up empty. 
Is this what you meant ? Or am I completely missing the ball ? :) Anyway: thanks for trying to help out !

Comment: A runnable jar must have a class having main method which works as an entry point to run it.

Comment: thank you for your suggestion, @AjayKumar. i added the 'mwave_sdk.jar' as a Referenced Library, but sadly that did not fix the issue. I have no clue how to proceed from here. I wish the error statement was more helpful, in telling me WHICH part is missing exactly.

Answer (score 1):

For what I can see, you just need to add that source(path to the .java files) to the project build path configuration in eclipse, I would be more specific, but I haven't used eclipse in a while, I found this: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/eclipse/eclipse_java_build_path.htm and I'm quite sure it will help you.

PS: Not a big fan of folders with spaces in their names.

Comment: Thank you for trying to help out, @DanielOcampo. I added the 'mwave_sdk.jar' as a Referenced Library in Eclipse (following that link you were so kind to provide), but that did not fix the issue. I still get the same error.